# Is it called something when someone argues with false reasoning?

Tags: phrase-requests

Is it called something when people argue with nonsense or unreasonable reasoning? I'll try to give a specific example using a silly subject, a cupcake

We eat Cupcakes because they're tasty. Lets say one day we wake up and find that 1/5th of all people find cupcakes bitter and not tasty. Someone who is a fan of cupcakes might say "the reason why people eat cupcakes is for the sugar rush" which is obviously not true. Another person may say muffins don't suffer bitterness in 1/5th of people like cupcakes do so they should serve muffins instead. The fan might say but muffins can't be used to soothe cuts because it lacks icing; which is ridiculous thing to say because noone actually would use icing to treat a cut, we want cupcakes so we can eat them

Is there a name for the way the "fan" argues?

Comment: Presumably, you're after something other than "nonsensical"?

Comment: With **an agenda**, you have **an ax to grind**. Logic is overrated.

Comment: This isn't exactly a [**fallacy**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/fallacy) in the [usual sense](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies).

Comment: The example just sounds like lying to me, or, if they are not lying, being wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Although I agree with Weather Vane due to the simplicity of the proposed argument, I would still just call this "fan's" argument **Fallacious**, and I think this is what you were looking for: a way to describe invalid arguments. [Fallacies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fallacies) are this sort of failure in logical reasoning, and although there's a whole lot of them you could specifically reference, the broad term **non sequitur** would work here, "where the conclusion does not logically follow the premise."

Comment: Revisiting this question now, I find Yosef Baskin's comment the most apt response. There's really no need to structure an argument with fancy fallacies if your opponent is intentionally nonsensical; you don't need to convince anyone they're wrong. They don't care that they are.

Answer (score 1):

The argument is **spurious**

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/spurious)
false and not what it appears to be, or (of reasons and judgments) based on something that has not been correctly understood and therefore false:

More forcefully, and particularly relevant to your question and example, Longman says:

[Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/spurious)
a spurious statement, argument etc is not based on facts or good thinking and is likely to be incorrect
*He demolished the Opposition’s spurious arguments.*

*spurious* has more force than *specious*, which describes at least a semblance of logic, whereas *spurious* describes something that is just plain wrong:

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/specious)
seeming to be right or true, but really wrong or false:

*spurious* is similar to but not synonymous with *fallacious*, which has implications of false reasoning, even from correct facts:

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fallacy)
an often plausible argument using false or invalid inference

So if the cupcake fan would listen long enough, you might say “Your silly cupcake arguments are fallacious because they are based on false logic, specious because they lead to the wrong conclusions, and worst of all are spurious because they are based on false facts”

Comment: How would I use this in a sentence when talking to the person? Do I say you are using spurious reasoning? You're using spurious arguments?

Comment: I have added a long example of use.